# Why doesn't my RPi show up on my network?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have read a number of posts on this topic, so I went into my router's network map to see what I could learn. I discovered that my RPi, which is connected by ethernet cable, has two different IP addresses. Could this cause it not to show up as a network share?

One of the IP addresses is a fixed address that I set in order to use the Pi as a Plex server. The Plex server function is working fine. Can I delete the other IP address, without messing things up? How do I do that? I'm obviously over my head when it comes to network administration. Thanks for any light you can shed on this problem.

Comment: If you have 2 IP addresses you have probably misconfigured networking, probably by attempting to set a static IP address. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) and if you REALLY must [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)
(You almost certainly don't NEED Static IP Address - this seems to be a Pi fixation.)

Comment: You are correct. I have a static IP as prescribed by the instructions I used to set up a Plex Media Server on my RPi. My primary question is this: is it the fact that I have 2 IP addresses that is preventing me from getting my Samba share to appear on my network? I can ping the RPi from an Ubuntu computer and from my Mac, and I can ping both of those from my RPi. I just can't see the RPi on the network.

Comment: It is not possible to say from the information provided. You haven't said HOW you configured networking or what addresses are in use. I don't know what "I can't see the RPi on the network" actually means.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your network setup, I'll make some assumptions.

Assumptions you're using a :
1. consumer router with DHCP enabled, so it'll be assigning IPs to your devices on your network.
2. good cable.

Remove your static IP setup (enable it again later if you must), to ensure that you're configured properly. Allow the OS, to obtain it's own IP.

Once you're setup, and able to access the network, then start assigning static IPs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my comment above in reply to Milliways. If I understand what you are saying, the fact of 2 IP addresses is confusing the networking issue. If I remove the static IP address and get the Samba sharing to work, why won't it stop working again if I reassign a static IP address? As you can no doubt tell, I am a noob at this stuff.

Comment: It should still work. If you made it identical, and all the settings are correct, it should still work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I got it working. I had failed to update and upgrade before setting up the smb.conf file. As soon as I did, it all started working. I am a happy camper.